# How to have my java program print newlines when outputting to a text file

Tags: java, word-wrap, filewriter, printwriter

For example, instead of getting this:

```
output 

output

output

output
```

I get this:

```
output output output output
```

I've tried to add something that would enter the output after writing like this:

```
output.write("\n")
```

but that doesn't do anything
Any suggestions???

Comment: what is the difference between both the outputs?

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Are you on windows? If so, you'll probably need `\r\n` instead of just `\n`

Comment: Your title is misleading. You are trying to print newlines, not have your text wrap.

Comment: @Perception then fix it, you have the rep!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - I could, but then he would never learn how to post questions properly.

Comment: @Perception Teach by example ...

Answer (score 3):

It is different based on which OS you are using.

A better approach is to use a [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) to wrap your `OutputStream` and use `println()` instead because it handles this automatically.

If you really insist on using `OutputStream` and the `.write()` method directly, what you want is to use the results of [`System.getProperty("line.separator");`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) as the end of line terminator.

You could read it once `private static final String EOL = System.getProperty("line.separator");` and re-use it over and over, but this is not the best practice by any means.

This way your program will work correctly regardless of which OS it is running on.

Comment: I think `\r\n` is an easier solution, but this is more universal.

Comment: @Jon Do you really think it is **good advice** in Java to put a platform specific sequence at the end of every `.write()` rather than correctly use `.println()` or the system property that is there for just this purpose? Really? Really?